# Why is this happening to my subdivided holes in my cylinder?

Tags: subdivision-surface

[image: Holes in mesh, but annoying glitch.]

I've used Shift-E but i still get glitches. I need subdivision surface for my whole other part of the mesh and it works fine there. It's a weapon so I need detail.

Comment: https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/what-is-the-problem-with-posting-an-image-or-link-and-asking-how-do-i-do-this

Answer (score 0):

Try to add edges like on the picture. But anyway this is a bad topology, you need to learn about it. 
[image]

Comment: Brief The Answer with clear Method.

Comment: I've done that before and it ruins the cylinder. It makes it bumpy. How do i make better topology?

Comment: Use this topology reference https://imgur.com/r/animation/dEWXP to make your topology better. And remember that using booleans for subdiv modeling is a bad idea.

Answer (score -1):

I did it another way, i'll have to live with some visible edges.

I used another cylinder, removed the face from one of the sides, made 3 loop cuts without moving them.

Got another cylinder, 90 degrees on the x axis and stretched them to fit in the cylinder. Selected all 3 and booleaned them with ctrl-f.

After that I used the solidify tool.

Moral is: dont extrude at the end of the cylinder as it will mess stuff up.

Comment: edited, sorry..